# Use spark SQL to read non-existing column with Parquet format

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have two month parquet file **2017_01.parquet** and **2017_08.parquet** and those schema is:

2017_01.parquet:

```
root
|-- value: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- version: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- major: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- minor: integer (nullable = true)
|    |-- guid: string (nullable = true)
```

2017_08.parquet:

```
root
|-- value: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- version: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- major: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- minor: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- vnum: integer (nullable = true)
|    |-- guid: string (nullable = true)
```

and my code

```
SQL = """
SELECT value.version.major,
       value.version.minor,
       value.version.vnum
FROM OUT_TABLE 
LIMIT 10"""

parquetFile = spark.read.parquet("/mydata/2017_08.parquet")
parquetFile.createOrReplaceTempView("OUT_TABLE")
out_osce = spark.sql(SQL)
out_osce.show()
```

When I load 2017_08.parquet show:

```
+-----+-----+----+
|major|minor|vnum|
+-----+-----+----+
| 0001| 4610|1315|
| 0002| 4610|6206|
| 0003| 4610|6125|
```

but if I load 2017_01.parquet like 
`parquetFile = spark.read.parquet("/mydata/2017_01.parquet")`

SQL show error :

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'No such struct field vnum in major, minor; line 4 pos 11'
```

I know the reason is 2017_01.parquet didn't have vnum column, and I have two slove solutions, one is using `mergeSchema` another is using schema when reading parquet file, but those ways also have a big problem.

The first solution need read 2017_08.parquet, if I don't need 08's data it will be a problem, and if bad luck vnum is an option column and 08 didn't have this column it still error

The second solution is given schema when read, like `spark.read.schema(schema).parquet("/mydata/2017_01.parquet")`, this way need to write schema first, but if the file is a very complex nested table, user maybe can't write the schema, and schema will update.

I want ask anyone have the third solution then make only read **2017_01.parquet** and output like:

```
+-----+-----+----+
|major|minor|vnum|
+-----+-----+----+
| 0001| 4600|null|
| 0002| 4600|null|
| 0003| 4600|null|
```

Comment: Thanks edit suggested @himanshuIIITian

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve similar problem by checking the DF's column list when creating select.
In my case the following was enough:

```
 parquetFile = spark.read.parquet("").withColumn("vnum", coalesce(if
 parquetFile.columns.contains("vnum") $"vnum" else lit(null)))
```

In your case, with nested schema, you can use something like:

```
// Define the full struct type schema to check if nested field exists.

val structToCheck = new StructField("value", new StructType().add("version",new StructType().add("major",StringType).add("minor",StringType).add("vnum",StringType)))

val SQL = """ SELECT value.version.major,
       value.version.minor,""" +
       if (parquetFile.schema.contains(structToCheck)) 
           "value.version.vnum" 
       else 
           "'' as vnum" +
       "FROM OUT_TABLE  LIMIT 10"
```

You can also do some more specific searches, getting the value.version structure and checking it's elements.

Comment: Hi Vapira, this is a good solution to example schema, but in real case my schema very huge, and I can't know what time it add a new column(data provider is other people), so use check function maybe have other issue. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use case statement or coalesce when reading:

```
parquetFile = spark.read.parquet("") \
              .withColumn("vnum", coalesce("vnum"))
```

From docs:

> coalesce(e: Column*): Column
>
> Returns the first column that is not null, or null if all inputs are
>   null.

If your Parquet file has this field, it will be used. If not, nulls will be used and new column will be in your schema

Comment: Hi T. Gawęda when I use coalesce("vnum") it always show error, so I try to use lit(""), but the problem is `.withColumn` the new column add on the top level, if i have nested schema it can't add the column to the right level

Comment: This is not a stable solution as I understand the column added only when it present in other rows but if there is no column at all this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a index table to store column situations for each parquet files, such as:

parquetfile1    column1, column2
parquetfile2    column1,  column3
.....

when read parquet files, read index data firstly to filter some files, then execute the query operations.